# print XML or TXT file from browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, thermal-printer

Is there any way for print a XML or TXT file from browser? I have a thermal printer and I want to send one of this format from browser with javascript. Usually, the browser dirty the file and the printer doesn't recognize the format.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want but we can use the window.print() function to open the print dialog for the user.

For exemple you can open your xml file in a new window and then use window.print().

```
window.open(file.txt);
window.print();
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Your code sample probably won't do what you intend. `window.open()` will open a popup, and a subsequent `window.print()` will attempt to print the current window, not the popup.

Comment: of course `window.print()` has to been executed on the new window but thanks for precision.

Comment: a simple windows.print() from browser send rubish from browser, the browser becomes the txt file and print, doesn't print directly the file.